# Is there a normed space $V$ such that there exists $v\in V$, $v\neq0$ that satisfies $\|v\|=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, normed-spaces

So my differential geometry teacher left (with an air of mistery) as an exercise to decide wether there exists any non-euclidean normed space $V$ such that there exists a curve $\underline{x}\colon I\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow V$ whose derivative satisfies $\underline{\dot{x}}(t)\neq0$ $\forall t\in I$ (except maybe a zero-measure set in $I$) and whose length (namely $\int_{a}^{b}{\|\underline{\dot{x}}(s)\|ds}$) is equal to zero. As I can suppose $I$ has non-zero measure and any norm is positive the only other option for that integral to equal $0$ is that the norm is zero for all $t\in I$ (except maybe, again, a zero-measure set in $I$), but I am quite sure that the norm of a vector being $0$ implies the vector itself being $0\in V$, wether $V$ is euclidean or not. I would submit that argument, but the fact that he was so enigmatic about it makes me think there's some other thing I'm overlooking, so if you could either reassure me on it or come up with a counterexample I'd be very thankful

Comment: It's part of the definition of a normed space that if $\| v \| = 0$ then $v = 0$.

Comment: They may be referring to an indefinite quadratic form, not strictly speaking a 'norm', but sometimes denoted in the same way. So a 'null'-vector is sometimes written as $\|v\|=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *non-Euclidean* is the key phrase. With the Lorentz metric $ds^2 = dx^2-dy^2$, take the path $\vec r(t) = (t,t)$, $0\le t\le 1$. Then $\vec r{}'(t) = (1,1)\ne 0$ for all $t$, but $\|\vec r{}'(t)\| = \sqrt{1^2-1^2} = 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: *Non-euclidean* normed space. What does that suggest? The professor was suggesting something out of the ordinary (with or without mystery) :) I agree that non-Riemannian would have been a better term.